# Multiple values in single Postgres database table column

Tags: database, postgresql

I recently took over as db admin for an app I am unfamiliar with. I was poking around the development db instance and found a table with multiple values in a single column. I am not sure how to query on this column as what I have tried thus far has not worked.

I have tried various characters between the column name and what looks like a key value pair in the column value itself. I am trying to select based on the state :name value. None of the below have worked and I have not yet found the postgres doc that addresses this.

```
select * from district where state = 'California';

select * from district where state:name = 'California';

select * from district where state_name = 'California';

select * from district where state[name] = 'California';

select * from district where state[:name] = 'California';
select * from district where state[0] = 'California';
```

Below is a specific entry from the table districts

```
id         | 8
name       | 13
state      | --- + | :name: California + | :abbr: CA + |
created_at | 2011-12-08 04:31:15.104002
updated_at | 2011-12-08 04:31:15.104002
```

Comment: That is a custom format, that does not follow anything I have seen. You will have to parse that yourself using `strpos()` and `substr()`. There is no built-in function to deal with such a "structured string". What will obviously work for the example at hand is `where state like '%California%'`

Comment: @Abelisto output below

select format('%L', state) from district where id = 8;
ERROR:  relation "district" does not exist
LINE 1: select format('%L', state) from district where id = 8;

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, this query works. Moving on to how to parse in ruby rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a regular expression:

```
WHERE name  ~ '\mCalifornia\M'
```